# How is Harry Potter able to ride his broomstick without getting sick?

Tags: harry-potter

On that thing, he's done lots of acceleration & sudden movements. Why do we not see him throwing up or dry heaving?

Comment: Why do we not see fighter pilots and stunt skydivers upheaving?

Comment: Genetics. He comes from a long line (at least 1 long) of excellent flyers

Comment: Magic brooms are magic.

Comment: If Harry Potter has never shown any signs of being motion sick (and I don't remember any) why would this even be a question? If anyone can show me an example where he has been motion sick, I will leave it, otherwise I will close it (if the community doesn't) by the end of the business day.

Comment: @Thaddeus Close it for what reason? It doesn't seem to match any of them. It's a poor question that deserves to, and probably will, be heavily downvoted, but seems to match the rules for what's allowed.

Comment: If this was reworded to, say, 'Are there any safety or comfort measures applied to flying broomsticks' I think it would be fair-to-middlin'

Comment: The question doesn't deal with any particular aspect of science fiction or fantasy. It is asking for a real world explanation of motion sickness and why or how a character who was never depicted as getting motion sick, didn't become motion sick. I will wait and see if the downvoting continues. I still don't think it is a relevant question.

Comment: Come on, Moon. Edit your question and let it run.

Answer (score 4):

Motion sickness is an illness in which a person's brain cannot match data from different metrics (I.E. observations taken from the eyes and inner ear), also known as [sensory conflict](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/09/23/rethinking-motion-sickness/?_r=0). It doesn't affect everyone in the same way, and indeed doesn't affect many people at all.

Harry is likely of the set of people whose brain is able (either via intrinsic nature or via concentrated effort) to process all incoming data and resolve conflicts.

This isn't really a sci fi question.